How can I evaluate this double combinatorial sum?
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and
\begin{equation}
f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n{n \choose i}{n \choose j}i^{n-j}j^{n-i}
\end{equation}
I would like to compute the following limit (from a Romanian Olympiad)
\begin{equation}
L= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Big(f(n)\Big)^{\frac{1}{2n}}\log n}{n}
\end{equation}
Do you have any simple hint to handle this limit ?
To simplify the limit $L$, we could find two functions $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ that have the same limit as $n$ tends to infinity and such that
\begin{equation}
g(n) \leq f(n) \leq h(n)
\end{equation}
but how to find such bounds ?
Many thanks

My first idea was to bound $i^{n-j}j^{n-i}\le n^{n-j}n^{n-i}$ but this gives $f(n)\le(n+1)^{2n}$, which is too crude.

This is problem 6252 in AMM, and they did post a solution which you can search for. The limit is $1/e$.

@CalvinLin. You could give a link ? Thanks.

AMM is available on Jstor, so search for 6252. The article requires a login.

Thank you for the information.
